# Elementary set theory question (not a rational set)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

not really sure where to begin with this question:

let

$$ A = \{x \in \mathbb{R}\space : \cos(x) \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

and

$$B = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : \sin(x) \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

prove or disprove:

$$A \cup B^c \nsubseteq \mathbb{Q}$$

Comment: Well, it contains $\pi$...

Comment: should it be $(A\cup B)^c$ or is it ok like that?

Comment: Oh, with it complemented like that you have a rather different problem.

Comment: That's as the question is written, no parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Find $A$ explicitly. For example, ask yourself: for which $x$ is $\mathrm{cos}(x)$ an integer?

Once you've done that, it should be easy to prove the statement.

Answer (score 0):

$A=\{\frac{\pi k}{2}\mid k\in \Bbb Z\}$